# parse html with single or double quotes

Tags: rebol, rebol3, red

When using the `parse` dialect, how to parse tags that have properties enclosed by `'` or '"`, as in:

```
thru <h2 class="txt-medium txt-bold">

thru <h2 class='txt-medium txt-bold'>
```

One way was to do:

```
thru {<h2 class=} thru {txt-medium txt-bold} thru ">"
```

Tried to use the `|` or operator but with no success. Can I use the `|` operator to parse the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `|` operator, but defining a charset is better in this case:

```
delimiter: charset [#"^"" #"'"]
single: {<h2 class='txt-medium txt-bold'>}
double: {<h2 class="txt-medium txt-bold">}

>> parse single [thru "class=" delimiter copy values to delimiter thru ">"] values
== "txt-medium txt-bold"

>> parse double [thru "class=" delimiter copy values to delimiter thru ">"] values 
== "txt-medium txt-bold"
```

The golden rule is to avoid `to` and `thru` when possible and define what to match.

Comment: This is of course simplified solution. It doesn't make sure that starting delimiter matches ending one. To improve it, you need to do something like:

    delimiters: charset [#"^"" #"'"]
    ; ...
    parse single [thru "class=" set delimiter delimiters copy values to delimiter thru ">"] values

Comment: The parsing in my Rebol `system/version` 3.0.0.4.40 does not return the `"txt-medium txt-bold"` as in your case. I get `== ""`